Control circuit of an AC circuit breaker with two SCRs
In this control circuit, I want to generate some pulses from a microcontroller. I intend to operate a circuit breaker using this control circuit. Therefore, I used a relay instead of a circuit breaker in Proteus. However, I am encountering some errors. Are the gate and cathode connections correct? How can I monitor the output signal? How can I simulate the microcontroller if I just want to produce some pulses instead of using the Arduino microcontroller?
I am not a specialist in electronics and only remember a few concepts from my university years.

An SCR to drive the base of a transistor doesn't look like a good idea. Also the gate trigger needs to be referenced to its cathode - not to the gate of another SCR. [Edit] your question and write a specification for what you are trying to achieve and we can take it from there.

There is no SCR .model built into LTspice. Did you get that syntax from Pspice or somewhere else?

The opto-isolator LEDs can be driven directly by a microcontroller with an appropriate series resistor in each. You don't need SCRs U1 and U2.
It's not clear what you're doing on the right hand side but it looks like you are trying to control an AC load but have only one load terminal and no AC supply terminal.
You could avoid all the complexity by using a TRIAC or, simpler still, a solid state relay which has the opto-isolator and TRIAC built in. What I've written about them here, Opto-triacs, solid-state relays (SSR), zero-cross and how they work may help you.
